# Difference between RWDBTBuffer<T>, RWDBVector<T> and RWDBDecimalVector

Tags: c++, database-connection, rogue-wave

I'm writing a python script to generate C++ classes used for database access and they use RogueWave types for data transfer. I have a few template classes I'm looking at to outline how the generated classes should look. When implementing a method for transferring several tuples in one operation, columns are wrapped in RWDBTbuffer, RWDBVector and RWDBDecimalVector.

My problem is, I can't see a direct correlation between the data type that is being wrapped (int, long, RWDateTime, RWDecimalPortable) and the container it is being placed in. It seems to me that I can just put everything in a RWDBTBuffer. What is the advantage of using RWDBDecimalVector over RWDBTBuffer for numeric types, and should RWDBVector ever be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in terms of data that they both store there isn't any different.
the main different is that you can shift `RWDBVector` into `RWDBReader` and then you can read the data into it.